# How to I reproduce Web Arial? - Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics, web-design

I'm designing web page elements in Photoshop at the moment, but...

**Arial** text in **Photoshop** looks **nothing** like the one displayed in **web pages**.

---

*Anything I can do about it?*

Answer (score 3):

Truthfully, *you shouldn't concern yourself* that much.

The appearance of fonts on web browsers is determined what which fonts are installed on the client's computer. Different browsers may render the same text, in the same font, on the same computer – differently.

The only way to truly see how your website will appear is to **create a test website** and view it in a variety of browsers. You are better off to create a design that is flexible enough to handle font inconsistencies that are inherent in the web development process.

Furthermore, there are other options on browsers such as "zoom in" and "zoom out" which affect the layout of text. This means that if your design is still at the mercy of the user of the website.

Answer (score 2):

Change the antialiasing and kerning options.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense. It's the same typeface. You sure you aren't looking at Verdana on the web? Until you post some screenshots, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean radianthex. it drives me crazy that the fonts don't reproduce correctly. The larger the point size the worse it gets. if anybody has an answer to this that'd be great

Comment: While I know your reputation isn't high enough to allow you to post comments on questions, the answers section should not include anything other than answers.  EDIT: had accidentally written "karma" instead of "reputation."